# Stop the whole component from re-rendering when the Redux store changes

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a functional component that renders a table with rows. Each row is populated with data stored in the Redux store as an array. Each row can also be removed and users can also undo the removal, if its within a given timeframe (via a toast).

The problem I'm facing is that when data for 1 row is removed from the Redux store array, the whole table gets re-rendered. Same for when it's added back into the array upon undoing the removal.

I understand that on each removal/undo, a new array is being created which gets persisted in the store, hence the re-renders. But is there a way I can optimize this, so that the whole table does not get re-rendered every time?

Comment: Seeing the relevant code, component structure/hierarchy would be helpful.

Comment: This may help: https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window

Comment: Are you fetching new json after removing and re creating the entire array? You can select the item by id for each item and add a [compare](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#equality-comparisons-and-updates) function to useSelector if all data is recreated after a delete/undo (re fetched).

Answer (score 0):

You can select each item in the row component, if you re create all items because you re fetch them then add a compare function:

```js
const { Provider, useDispatch, useSelector } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } = Redux;
const { createSelector } = Reselect;

const initialState = {
  items: [
    { id: 1, name: 'one' },
    { id: 2, name: 'two' },
    { id: 3, name: 'three' },
  ],
};
//action types
const REMOVE = 'REMOVE';
//action creators
const remove = (itemId) => ({
  type: REMOVE,
  payload: { itemId },
});
const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  if (type === REMOVE) {
    const { itemId } = payload;
    return {
      ...state,
      items: state.items.filter(({ id }) => id !== itemId),
    };
  }
  return state;
};
//selectors
const selectItems = (state) => state.items;
const createSelectItemById = (itemId) =>
  createSelector([selectItems], (items) =>
    items.find(({ id }) => id === itemId)
  );
//creating store with redux dev tools
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(
      () => (next) => (action) => next(action)
    )
  )
);
const Item = React.memo(function Item({ itemId }) {
  console.log('creating jsx for item:', itemId);
  const selectItemById = React.useMemo(
    () => createSelectItemById(itemId),
    [itemId]
  );
  const item = useSelector(selectItemById);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <li>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(item)}</pre>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(remove(itemId))}>
        remove
      </button>
    </li>
  );
});
const App = () => {
  const items = useSelector(selectItems);
  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map(({ id }) => (
        <Item key={id} itemId={id} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reselect/4.0.0/reselect.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

If that doesn't work for you because all items are recreated then you can have a build in memoization in the createSelectItemById:

```js
const { Provider, useDispatch, useSelector } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } = Redux;
const { createSelector } = Reselect;

const initialState = {
  items: JSON.stringify([
    { id: 1, name: 'one' },
    { id: 2, name: 'two' },
    { id: 3, name: 'three' },
  ]),
};
//action types
const REMOVE = 'REMOVE';
//action creators
const remove = (itemId) => ({
  type: REMOVE,
  payload: { itemId },
});
const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  if (type === REMOVE) {
    const { itemId } = payload;
    return {
      ...state,
      items: JSON.stringify(
        JSON.parse(state.items).filter(
          ({ id }) => id !== itemId
        )
      ),
    };
  }
  return state;
};
//selectors
// re creating items every time
const selectItems = (state) => JSON.parse(state.items);
const createSelectItemById = (itemId) => {
  //comparing last to current and returning last
  //  if items are the same
  let lastItem = {};
  return createSelector([selectItems], (items) => {
    const currentItem = items.find(
      ({ id }) => id === itemId
    );
    //only need to compare name, you may need more comparisons
    if (currentItem.name === lastItem.name) {
      return lastItem;
    }
    lastItem = currentItem;
    return currentItem;
  });
};
//creating store with redux dev tools
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(
      () => (next) => (action) => next(action)
    )
  )
);
const Item = React.memo(function Item({ itemId }) {
  console.log('creating jsx for item:', itemId);
  const selectItemById = React.useMemo(
    () => createSelectItemById(itemId),
    [itemId]
  );
  const item = useSelector(selectItemById);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <li>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(item)}</pre>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(remove(itemId))}>
        remove
      </button>
    </li>
  );
});
const App = () => {
  const items = useSelector(selectItems);
  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map(({ id }) => (
        <Item key={id} itemId={id} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reselect/4.0.0/reselect.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```